# Image translation is clipped (how to prevent)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, clipping

How can I force a UI object to NOT be clipped when it's partly outside the screen. I have an image that doesn't fit inside the screen completely. When I drag it (TranslateY) it moves like it's supposed to but the problem is that the part that was outside the screen doesn't appear so the image is abruptly cut. The only part of the image that is visibly moving is the part that originally fit to the screen.

Ps. Please do not recommend scollviewer as this is about a gesture to do a specific thing on the UI and ScrollViewer is not ok for that.

This is basically the XAML (The image is twice the height of the display)

```
<Grid x:Name="GestureScreen" ManipulationMode="TranslateY"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"> 
    <Image x:Name="GestureImage" CacheMode="BitMapCache" Source="Assets/bg/draggable.png" />
</Grid>
```

This is the C# (not really relevant, but still)

```
void GestureScreen_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    move.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Comment: Throw a negative margin on your image.

Comment: Negative margin doesn't solve the problem (the image would then clip at the top).

Comment: It shouldn't clip anything but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't clip (can't test before tomorrow) but negative margin would position it incorrectly. Surely there has to be a better way to do this than to hack it with a negative margin and then somehow positioning it back to counter the negative margin.

Comment: Honestly I didn't even read your whole question when I commented, I'll come back to it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a row and column for the image which directly specifies `Auto` for both. That way the image will size to its actual size and not the current size of the `*` *defaults* of the screen size. Hence you will have the whole image as dragged.

Comment: This actually makes sense (long day and I was thinking that the image moves inside the grid like it did before I changed the code). I'll have to try this tomorrow to see if it solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: This was the solution. The container didn't expand with the content longer than what was visible on the screen. By defining a height of the parent (total of the children) the child objects are now visible when dragging. In other words (Grid Height="1600"). Auto worked as well as long as you define it in the rowdefinition and not the grid itself (makes more sense to keep it dynamic). Thanks!